# Inputing number between a range in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two input fields of type number, one for minimum value and the other for maximum value. At any given time user can update these values, but the minimum value cannot be greater than maximum value and vice versa. These are my functions which I am calling on 'onChange' event of input:

```
function minValUpdateHandler(e) {
  setMin((prevVal) => {
  const valInNum = +e.target.value;
  if (valInNum < max) {
    return valInNum;
  }
   return prevVal;
 });
}

function maxValUpdateHandler(e) {
  setMax((prevVal) => {
  const valInNum = +e.target.value;
  if (valInNum > min) {
    return valInNum;
  }
  return prevVal;
 });
}
```

And [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-tu-g0xv6q?file=/src/App.js:169-561) is the codesandbox link for the POC.
Please assist me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Your POC has `onChnage`, not `onChange`. The functions are never called.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I corrected it. Now try entering a min value and then update the max value. e.g; min value as 10 and then try to eneter max value as 50

Comment: That's to be expected, since `5` is less than 10. You will need to do the min/max validation e.g. only after focus leaves the control (`onBlur`).

Answer (score 2):

the problem was the type of value, the type of value is String so '9' can be bigger than '10' this code can solve the problem

`parseInt(e.target.value,10);` also, you can not set the min attribute from min input and either max for max input

I suggest using `return max-1;` instead of `return prevVal`
and `return min+1;` instead of `return prevVal`

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [min, setMin] = useState(0);
  const [max, setMax] = useState(100);

  function minValUpdateHandler(e) {
    setMin((prevVal) => {
      const valInNum = +parseInt(e.target.value);
      if (valInNum < max) {
        return valInNum;
      }
      return max-1;
    });
  }

  function maxValUpdateHandler(e) {
    setMax((prevVal) => {
      const valInNum = +parseInt(e.target.value);
      if (valInNum > min) {
        return valInNum;
      }
      return min+1;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Min Max input</h1>
      <div className="inputContainer">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="min">Min</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="min"
            value={min}
            max={max - 1}
            onChange={minValUpdateHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <span>-</span>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="max">Max</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="max"
            value={max}
            min={min + 1}
            onChange={maxValUpdateHandler}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```